# Operator analogous to += or .= in PL/SQL?

Tags: php, sql, oracle, plsql, concatenation

I'd like to know whether there's an operator I could use in `PL/SQL` so that I could concatenate Strings with themselves, like what, for example we have in **PHP**:

```
$myStr .= "more text";
```

Which means: `$myStr` receives itself plus the string `"more text"`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While I don't believe there are compound assignment operators in PL/SQL, the string concatenation operator is `||` so at least you can do this:

```
my_str := my_str || 'more text';
```

Answer (score 5):

To my knowledge there is only `||` to concatenate strings and the `concat` function.

See

- http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/concat2.php and
- http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/concat.php

Comment: SO everytime you use an `out` variable and need to keep updating it you need to do `o_myVar := o_myVar || 'something';` ??